# Unable to delete non-quad faces

Tags: python, scripting, edit-mode

Given below is the code. First I make a cone(frustum), then I go through all the faces and select the faces with more than 4 vertices, that will be the 2 circular faces on the top and bottom. The ones on the sides are of 4 vertices. Then I delete the selected faces. This doesn't seem to be working and I am getting a single vertex at the origin as the output. I am new to blender and am not able to find the error.

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cone_add(
        vertices=32,
        radius1=10,
        radius2=5,
        depth=10,
        location=(0,0,0),
        rotation=(0,0,0)
)

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.object.join()

obj = bpy.context.active_object  
me = obj.data

# must be in object mode, to refresh face selections and data
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT') 

faces = me.polygons
for f in faces:
    f.select = (len(f.vertices) != 4)

# to remove using this method we switch to edit mode, and back after removal.

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT') 
bpy.ops.mesh.delete(type='FACE')
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
```

Comment: You have to set the selection mode to `FACE` in edit mode before selecting in object mode. `bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')`then `bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type='FACE')`

Comment: It is working, thanks a lot @lemon

Comment: ... or use `end_fill_type='NONE'` to create without in the first place

Comment: Works faster, thanks @batFINGER. `end_fill_type='NOTHING'`.